# TortoiseHg aborts unknown format when cloning

Tags: mercurial, format, clone, tortoisehg

I am using windows explorer to clone a repository from a folder in a mapped drive into my local working folder. I have never encountered this problem before with any of my previous repositories, but I keep getting an error while the directory is cloned. The error points to a file that is of "unkown format". This is the exact error:

```
abort: index data/Scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/dialog.css.i unknown format 5661!
```

About half of the repository gets cloned, but it never finishes because of that error half way through. I have used a remote command that supposedly skips over unknown formats (I found it somewhere online), but it doesn't work. This would be the complete command:

```
hg clone --remotecmd skip-unknown-format --verbose -- Q:\mercurial-repository\east C:\working
```

Any pointers on how I can skip that one file and/or how I can fix this error?

This is my hg version info:
version 2.4
with Mercurial-2.2.1, Python-2.6.6, PyQt-4.8.6, Qt-4.7.4

Comment: I'm guessing a [corrupted remote repository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption). Try copying it to your PC and running `hg verify`.

Comment: I agree with @Helgi — the repository is corrupt. If the repository format had changed on disk, you would instead see `abort: requirement 'something' not supported!`. Finally, there's no `skip-unknown-format` magic remote command that you can run to get around this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. It was a corrupt file after all. I copied the file (and the .i file from the hg folder) from another repository to that one and re-ran the clone successfully.

Comment: I has the same error, which pointing on one particular file. I thought it's my  repository is corrupt. I reload whole project in new folder. It was ok, then after few weeks and few changes from team, I again got the same error with the same file, - it was changed by other people. Interesting that other people does not meet this problem. So I am thinking this is a some Tortoise bug or may be some version conflict.